# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor' - Getting this error when trying to use pd.read_sql() with flask-sqlalchemy query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a flask-sqlalchemy query. I know that the below flask-sqlalchemy query code is valid because I am able to populate data on another page in an html table with the 'eintest' variable.

```
ticker = 'msft'
eintest = db.session.query(company).filter(company.instance==ticker)
```

All I am trying to do is convert that flask-sqlalchemy code above into a pandas data frame, as I am trying to do below.

```
df = pd.read_sql(eintest.statement, db.session.bind)
```

When I run my flask app, I get the error, "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'". Does anyone know why this is? I've been trying many variations of that one line to read sql into a pandas dataframe but no luck yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments for pandas `read_sql` is a [sql statement and a connection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html). You are passing a statement and a [session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html). Here's what you'll need to change to get it to work:

```py
# Load to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_sql(eintest.statement, db.get_engine())
```

Comment: to future self:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75282511/df-to-table-throw-error-typeerror-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument