# df to table throw error TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'schema'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, azure-databricks

I have dataframe in pandas :- purchase_df. I want to convert it to sql table so I can perform sql query in pandas. I tried this method

```
purchase_df.to_sql('purchase_df', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

It throw an error

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'schema'
```

I have dataframe name purchase_df and I need to perform sql query on it. I need to perform sql query on this dataframe like this ....`engine.execute('''select * from purchase_df where condition''')`. For this I need to convert dataframe into sql table as in our server pandas_sql is not installed only sql alchemy is installed.

I ran this code in pycharm locally and it work perfectly fine but when i tried this in databrick notebook it is showing an error. Even though week ago it was running fine in databrick notebook too. Help me to fix this.

note:- pandas version '1.3.4'
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.0

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM i couldn't understand, please elaborate in detail

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM
I have dataframe name purchase_df and I need to perform sql query on it. I need to perform sql query on this dataframe like this ....engine.execute('''select * from purchase_df where condition'''). For this I need to convert dataframe into sql table as in our server pandas_sql is not installed only sql alchemy is installed. When i did locally then it works but not in databricks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems that the [version 2.0.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/) (realeased on January 26, 2023) of SQLAlchemy is not compatible with earlier versions of [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas).
I suggest you to *upgrade* your pandas version to the latest  ([version 1.5.3)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.3.html) with :

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Or:

```
conda upgrade pandas
```

Comment: Using `!pip install --upgrade pandas` solved the issue on the Azure Databricks environment. It warned that "Can't uninstall 'pandas'. No files were found to uninstall.", but when doing `!pip freeze`, the new version (1.5.3) was listed, and the "multiple values for argument 'schema'" error was gone.

Answer (score 13):

I got the same issue in databricks, and I had to downgrade sql alchemy to !pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.46

Answer (score 1):

I experience exactly the same issue with databricks at AWS. I try upper solutions but nothing works for me. So i install sqlalchemy-databricks library instead of SQLAlchemy and everything is back to life. https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-databricks/
Please uninstall/purge SQLAlchemy first to not be in conflict with sqlalchemy-databricks.

Comment: Good find - thanks. Annoying that AWS ELB is stuck at Python 3.7 otherwise an update of numpy and pandas could've solved it.