# Conda environment yaml has more dependencies than needed

Tags: anaconda, conda

conda==4.12.0

I'm trying to [generate a clean conda environment yaml](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#exporting-the-environment-yml-file) of my project and I noticed that there were some dependencies ending up in this file that maybe shouldn't be. The script to generate the environment yaml looks like this:

```bash
# Remove environment if it exists
yes | conda remove --name py37_clean --all

# create new environment
yes | conda create -n py37_clean python=3.7 pip
conda activate py37_clean
pip install -r ../requirements.txt

# create yaml file
conda env export > ../environment.yml

# exit environment and delete
conda deactivate
yes | conda remove --name py37_clean --all
```

When it generates `environment.yml`, I noticed that there was at least one dependency listed that didn't seem necessary,  `- pytorch=1.3.1=cpu_py37h0c87eb2_0` and I became concerned that it was defining other dependencies that may not be needed. It's possible this is required by some other package, but I tried to test this with `mamba repoquery depends -t pytorch` and it couldn't find anything. This command did work for other packages I tested so I think it is working. Any thoughts on why pytorch (and possibly other dependencies) were added? I think it is related to this note in the earlier link

```
This file handles both the environment's pip packages and conda packages.
```

But I'm not sure how to limit the conda packages to only what is necessary. I think I'm working with miniconda since `which conda` shows `/Users/[me]/miniconda3/condabin/conda`

My requirements.txt look like this:

```
boto3==1.26.117
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.15  # required by pyspark
pandas==1.0.5  # required by pyspark
pre-commit==2.21.0
praw==7.7.0
pg8000==1.29.4  # this was easier to pip install than psycopg2
pyarrow==2.0.0
pyspark==3.3.0  # using this version because py37 deprecated in pyspark 3.4.0
scikit-learn==1.0.2
seaborn==0.11.2
shap==0.41.0
sqlalchemy==1.4.46  # originally tried 2.0.10, but this was incompatible with old versions of pandas https://stackoverflow.com/a/75282604/5034651
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

The problem was I don't think the conda environment was even being activated by the above script. I was encountering [the error here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61915607/commandnotfounderror-your-shell-has-not-been-properly-configured-to-use-conda) and the solution was to add `source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate` at the top of my script. I did not need `conda init bash` like some people suggested.

After this, I was able to build the environment I wanted with minimal dependencies.

Comment: That's not what `conda clean` does - it won't remove any packages from an environment. It edits package cache, locks, and index files. Activation sounds like the only issue.

Comment: okay I see that now, `conda list` shows those packages were still installed